# plot function failed in dolphindb

Tags: plot, dolphindb

I'm using the `plot` function in DolphinDB generate diagrams by following the given examples in the user guide. I successfully created a multiYAxis plot by following the example in the user guide of plot. But I failed using my own data. Anything wrong with my code?
Here’s my code:

```
plot([tmp.count, tmp.sum], tmp.label,, LINE, ,  {multiYAxes : true})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DolphinDB function `plot` in this way:

```
tmp=loadText("/home/appadmin/test/temp.csv")
label=1..size(tmp)
plot([tmp.count, tmp.sum], label,, LINE, ,{multiYAxes : true})
```

And the plot will be shown like this

[image]